# database query planning and performance optimization, internals, basics

Tags: performance, rdbms

Where can I read some articles or watch video lectures/presentations on the internals of RDBMS query planning and performance optimization?
About how it works, an inside view, any pieces of computer science behind it, etc.

Comment: Please first start by reading in the guidelines what questions to ask here and what questions are considered off-topic here. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular goal you have, or a problem you are experiencing that could make for a better question and chance for answer?

Comment: I am joining a project and some part of it is a database engine. I would like to improve my understanding of the project in this aspect. That is why I'm asking this question.